# Removed/Deleted all services (VPC, EC2, DBs, etc), yet it is still showing 36 active services on AWS. How?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-billing

Specifically **Hong-Kong** region, aws name: **ap-east-1**. Early March 6th I deleted all EC2 instances, DBs, VPC and corresponding subnets, etc, yet today is end of March 7 and it incurred $57.

I will include 3 pictures where it is showing details.

1. List of EC2 instances by Region [image: List of EC2 instances by Region]
2. March 7 incurred charges in ap-east-1 [image: March 7 incurred charges in ap-east-1]
3. VPC dashboard in ap-east-1 [image: VPC dashboard in ap-east-1]

First picture shows 2 running EC2 instances in US.

Second picture shows in chart of incurred charges for March 7.
How it is incurring charges if each and every service for that region is deleted?

Third picture shows it VPC dashboard for ap-east-1. I went through each category and removed them.

Where else should I look for?
Do I wait for AWS update its usage and bill?

Filtered the bill from all angles. Went through region by region to turn off each and all possible service that may contribute.

Comment: This is a question for AWS customer (billing) support, not Stack Overflow.